# Passing Model from view to controller using Ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I trying to send the Model to controller by using Ajax call. The problem is that in Controller all the properties of the view are null.

My viewModel is:

```
public class ActivityDetailsViewModel
    {
    public ActivityDto Activity { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    public bool UpdateFinancialDataRight { get; set; }
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public bool HasViewFinancialDataRight
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(UserRole.ViewFinancialData) ||
                   HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(UserRole.UpdateActivityFinancialData);
        }
    }
    public bool HasUpdateFinancialDataRight
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(UserRole.UpdateActivityFinancialData);
        }
    }
    public bool IsInEdit { get; set; }
    public ActivityDetailsViewModel()
    {

    }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public ActivityDetailsViewModel(ActivityDto activity,int?parentId,int?projectId, string clientName, string projectName, string parent, bool updateFinancialDataRight,int? level,bool isInEdit)
    {
        this.Activity = activity;
        this.ClientName = clientName;
        this.ProjectName = projectName;
        this.Parent = parent;
        this.ParentId = parentId;
        this.ProjectId = projectId;
        this.Level = level;
        this.IsInEdit = isInEdit;
        StartDate = Utils.DateUtils.IntToDate(activity.StartDate);
        EndDate = Utils.DateUtils.IntToDate(activity.EndDate);
        UpdateFinancialDataRight = updateFinancialDataRight;
    }
}
```

In my view I have the following:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Activities", new { activityId = @Model.Activity.Id }, new AjaxOptions() { OnBegin = "beforeSaving('" + @Model.Activity.Id + "')", OnSuccess = "handleSuccess" }))
              {
                  <input id="btnRun" type="submit"  value="submit" />   

                     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ParentId, new { @class = "hiddenFiled" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectId, new { @class = "hiddenFiled" })
                   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Level, new { @class = "hiddenFiled" })
```

.........
}

The ajax call:

```
$("#btnRun").click(function (e) {
    debugger;
    e.preventDefault();
    var check = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Activities/Save',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(check),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });       
});
```

and in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(ActivityDetailsViewModel view)
    {  
        return PartialView("ActivitiesDetailsWindow", view);
    }
```

Comment: You should create ViewModels in frontend.

Comment: why do you need to send it via ajax call, when your page about to get submit and you have set `HttpPost` controller action will have your values if you have passed ViewModel in controller action. What exactly you want to achieve? Please elaborate.

Comment: Before send to the controller if a view's property was modified I have a popup (a popup with yes/no) and I would like to set a variable with the result of the popup

Answer (score -1):

In AJAX call you are sending data as string:

```
data: JSON.stringify(check),
```

You must provide a name to object in AJAX call and it should same as the argument name in targeted controller action method. And there is no need to stringfy JSON object at client. So it should be something like:

```
data: { myObject1: check},
```

and Since you are sending JSON from client so action method should be like:

```
 public ActionResult Save(string myObject1 )
```

Then inside action you can deserialize the JSON object and create model or whatever processing you need.